# Angular 2+ localization (i18n) rtl support

Tags: angular, typescript, localization, right-to-left

What is the best practice for adding right to left (rtl) support into a localized Angular 2+ app (e.g. for Hebrew and Arabic languages)? I looked through several tutorials including [Internationalization (i18n)](https://angular.io/guide/i18n) but none seem to be covering that. I would expect, for example, the html direction property (e.g. `<html dir="rtl">`) to be added along with translations defined in 18n attributes at the build step of the app.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible to add `i18n-dir` as [described in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#add-i18n-translation-attributes). So, the best approach I found so far is to add `i18n-dir dir="ltr"` (where `ltr` is a default direction) to the root element in the the root component template (e.g. `app.component.html`) like so:

```
<div i18n-dir dir="ltr">
    <!-- The rest of the content --> 
</div>
```

Once you generate translation files a corresponding `trans-unit` will appear in each of them with `source` containing default direction, which is `ltr` in this case. So, you just need to set the `target` of the unit to `rtl` for corresponding languages.

Comment: Happy to help @galvan 

Comment: I can't find any mention of an i18n-dir in Angular... has it been removed? Did it ever exist?

Comment: @DanielCrisp as the docs say: "To mark an attribute for translation, add an attribute in the form of i18n-x, where x is the name of the attribute to translate." They use `title` and `i18n-title` in the examples. So, in our case, these are `dir` and `i18n-dir`.

Comment: Ahh I see - brilliant. Nice idea. I was looking for a directive.

Comment: @TimOsadchiy will you explain how it works in angular 7 with Internationalization support

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the main `index.html` (and some other files) isn't a template and you can't do some stuff with it (e. g. translation). See [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8759).

But because it is an easy process, I tried to do it myself:

1. Create a translated version of your main `index.html` and insert it in a folder that named the code of your `rtl` language (`fa` in my case):

   **src/fa/index.html**:

   ```
   <!doctype html>
   <html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>عنوان برنامه</title>
       <base href="/fa/">

       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
       <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
       <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">

       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
   <app-root></app-root>
   <noscript>برای ادامه استفاده از این برنامه لازم است JavaScript را فعال کنید.</noscript>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

   <sup>*Especially see **`lang="fa"`** and **`dir="rtl"`** and **native texts**.*</sup>
2. In the related build configurations (in my case: `production-fa` and `fa`) in your `angular.json` file put:

   ```
   "index": "src/fa/index.html"
   ```

**Done.**

---

You can do same with other languages (*Even `ltr`s! Because of other changes that we made in `index.html`*).

To better understanding I also insert related build scripts in my `package.json` file:

```
    "start-fa": "ng serve --configuration=fa",
    "build-fa": "ng build --configuration=fa",
    "build-prod-fa": "ng build --prod --configuration=production-fa",
```

---

Bonus: What about `manifest.json` file (in case you want an installable PWA)?

The first step like above. Create a translated version in `src/fa/manifest.json`:

```
{
    "dir": "rtl",
    "lang": "fa",
    "name": "نام بلند برنامه",
    "short_name": "نام کوتاه",
    "theme_color": ...
    ...
```

But the second step is a little more difficult. I couldn't find a way to define its path. You can replace the original (`src/manifest.json`) with this one. You must do it BEFORE the build process starts (*not after it by replacing `dist/.../manifest.json`; because `@angular/service-worker` needs to know its final state during the build process*). So in your `package.json`:

```
"build-prod-fa": "cp src/fa/manifest.json src/manifest.json && ng build --prod --configuration=production-fa",
```

And revert it to its default version (in my case the default language is `en`) before the default production build:

```
"build-prod": "cp src/en/manifest.json src/manifest.json && ng build --prod",
```

Note that about `manifest.json` just `production` builds are important. Because `serviceWorker` is enabled only in these configurations by default (see your `angular.json` file).

---

<sup>*I know this is not an ideal solution. Because you will need to edit your sources (in these two files) in multiple places.*</sup>

Answer (score -1):

As of 2017, it appears that the Angular team is too busy and too few to add right-to-left (rtl) support to the angular-translate module (https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/260).

Not a big deal though, because it's pretty easy to do this with just native JS...

```
document.body.setAttribute("dir", "rtl");
```

In my experience, HTML5 does a pretty good job of getting rtl support done correctly.