# How to change the angular 7 functionalities for implementing rtl language support?

Tags: angular, web, localization, right-to-left, angular7

I have been doing a website in angular 7 which supports both English and Arabic language. I almost completed the English designs. I am stuck at doing the RTL design .  Not in html and css codes but in angular 7 functionalities.

Pretty much looking for a clean logic from start. 
We tried to use multiple css per page. But that did not work well.  Is there any other possible ways i could make use of? If there, share your ideas.

[Angular 2+ localization (i18n) rtl support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898361/angular-2-localization-i18n-rtl-support) 
I used this to flip the website .

Comment: Seriously ? Nobody knows about this? I got tumble weed badge for this.