# when user select language in arabic the layout of the page should be in right to left in angular

Tags: angular

In angular application when user select language in arabic the layout of the page should be in right to left and in english it should be left to right

Comment: That is a statement. What is your question? Have you tried researching this topic before? Googling "angular RTL support" yields results such as: https://medium.com/quick-code/rtl-support-in-angular-b7de22946972, https://coderwall.com/p/jl3zyw/angular-internationalisation-adding-rtl-support, https://material.angular.io/cdk/bidi/overview etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below links

[RTL Support in Angular](https://medium.com/quick-code/rtl-support-in-angular-b7de22946972)

[angular-2-localization-i18n-rtl-support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898361/angular-2-localization-i18n-rtl-support)